# which jaxb plugin to use?

Tags: java, maven-2, jaxb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference of Maven JAXB plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432859/difference-of-maven-jaxb-plugins)

I found two jaxb maven plugins:

```
1.
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>

2. 
    <groupId>com.sun.tools.xjc.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jaxb-plugin</artifactId>
```

What is difference in these two plugins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`maven-jaxb-plugin` supports jaxb1.0 and this has not been updated [since June 2005.](http://maven-plugins.sourceforge.net/maven-jaxb-plugin/changes-report.html#1_1_0)

The `maven-jaxb2-plugin` supports JAXB 2.1.

See more [on this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432859/difference-of-maven-jaxb-plugins)