# Java6 XML binding integration in Maven

Tags: xml, maven-2, xsd, java-6

When developing with Java6, is there any Maven plugin for compiling an XML schema into the associated Java classes from Maven?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference of maven jaxb plugins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432859/difference-of-maven-jaxb-plugins)

Answer (score 0):

Try the [maven-jaxb2-plugin](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/MJIIP/User+Guide).