# What Maven2 plugins are available for JAXB2?

Tags: maven-2, jaxb, jaxb2, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I'd like to generate Java source code from an XML Schema file using JAXB2 via a Maven2 plugin (as in [this blog post](http://blog.frankel.ch/customize-your-jaxb-bindings)).

There seem to be 2 Maven plugins for JAXB: The ["Maven 2 JAXB 2.x Plugin"](http://java.net/projects/maven-jaxb2-plugin/pages/Home) (org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin) is hosted at java.net, and the ["Maven JAXB 2.1 Plugin"](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/) (org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin) hosted at Codehaus.

It seems to me the one at java.net has more features, like XJC plugins. But its java.net page refers to [highsource.org](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/MJIIP/Documentation) for documentation, which unfortunately seems to be unavailable recently.

So what's the best choice? Does anyone know what's going on with highsource.org? What's everyone else using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference of Maven JAXB plugins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432859/difference-of-maven-jaxb-plugins)

Comment: Pretty sure highsource[dot]org is no longer a legitimate site S/O users would want to visit.. May wish to revise the question/post.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the following to be working well enough for my system.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Yup, that's the one from highsource.org. Glad that it's available again.