# Consume SOAP WSDL by calling its generated proxy class

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

Hello I've to consume SOAP service in java I've generated proxy class here is the list of classes which are generated

```
1)Bill.java
2)BillInfo.java
3)GetBillInfo.java
4)GetBillInfoResponse.java
5)ObjectFactory.java
```

now Sample input given to me by client is as following

```
-<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
-<soap:Body>
-<bil:getBillInfo xmlns:ns2="http://billpay.ws.bi.com/" xmlns:bil="http://billpay.ws.bi.com/">
-<billInfo>
-<bill>
<consumerNo>10300075929</consumerNo>
<shortName>SNGPL</shortName>
</bill>
<channel_id>100</channel_id>
<password>XXXXXX</password>
<username>xxx</username>
<webServiceID>3000</webServiceID>
<STAN>439624</STAN>
<channelType>Mobile</channelType>
</billInfo>
</bil:getBillInfo>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

and output from this input is as follows

```
-<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
-<S:Body>
-<ns2:getBillInfoResponse xmlns:ns2="http://billpay.ws.bi.com/">
-<return>
-<bill>
<billAmount>150.00</billAmount>  
<billConsumerName>GOHER PIRZADA </billConsumerName>
<billMonth>2016-01</billMonth>
<consumerNo>10300075929 </consumerNo>
<dueDate>2017-08-19</dueDate>
<lateAmount>160.00</lateAmount>
<shortName>SNGPL</shortName>
<utilityCompanyAccount>900083181010586</utilityCompanyAccount>
</bill>
<channel_id>0</channel_id>
<password/>
<status>Processed OK</status>
<statusCode>0</statusCode>
<username/>
<webServiceID>0</webServiceID>
</return>
</ns2:getBillInfoResponse>
</S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

these are the sample which are given to me now to implement this service for which I've written the following code but it does not work and does not return values please look into my code

```
GetBillInfo gbi = new GetBillInfo();
    BillInfo bi = new BillInfo();
    bi.setChannelId(100);
    bi.setPassword("XXXXXX");
    bi.setUsername("xxx");
    bi.setWebServiceID(3000);
    bi.setChannelType("Mobile");
    bi.setSTAN("439624");
    Bill bill = new Bill();
    bill.setConsumerNo("10300012345");
    bill.setShortName("SNGPL");
    gbi.setBillInfo(bi);

    ObjectFactory of=new ObjectFactory();
    JAXBElement<GetBillInfo> jbx = of.createGetBillInfo(gbi);
```

Here I do not get any response please let me know what mistake I'm making. Please let me know how to call which code by looking at the SOAP input and output values

Comment: The ObjectFactory only creates the objects you need to send. What is missing is the actual service class, which has a method, probably getBillInfo, to which you can give the object as a parameter.

Comment: objectFactory class have these two methods
    @XmlElementDecl(namespace = "http://billpay.ws.bi.com/", name = "getBillInfo")
    public JAXBElement<GetBillInfo> createGetBillInfo(GetBillInfo value) {
        return new JAXBElement<GetBillInfo>(_GetBillInfo_QNAME, GetBillInfo.class, null, value);
    }

Comment: The ObjectFactory is just for creating the classes, it will not send or receive anything. Ok, let's start the other wayy round... How did you create your proxy classes? wsimport?

Comment: and  @XmlElementDecl(namespace = "http://billpay.ws.bi.com/", name = "getBillInfoResponse")
    public JAXBElement<GetBillInfoResponse> createGetBillInfoResponse(GetBillInfoResponse value) {
        return new JAXBElement<GetBillInfoResponse>(_GetBillInfoResponse_QNAME, GetBillInfoResponse.class, null, value);
    }

Comment: this is how I generated my proxy classes from the following example http://memorynotfound.com/spring-ws-consume-soap-service-wsdl/

Comment: Seems like a horrible complicated way to create a client, google `wsimport`, which is a java standard tool and will give you some classes you can use without further configuration needed. Otherwise follow the other instructions on that page to use your classes to send the data.

Comment: could u please tell how generate proxy classes with wsimport for Spring Boot application in Eclipse

Answer (score 2):

One basic way of accessing a SOAP WebService is via `wsimport`, which is a java standard tool, included in the jdk.

Basically, you are calling it like this...

```
wsimport -Xnocompile http://example.com/someService?wsdl
```

...or whatever the location of your wsdl is, can be a local file, too. You can customize it by giving the parameters `-d` (destination folder) and `-`p (the package you want to create). The -Xnocompile parameter simply makes it give you .java files and not compiled .class files.

After you used that command, you will get some clases. you can then use them like this...

```
BillService service = new BillService();
BilLServicePortType port = service.getBillServicePort();
ObjectFactory of=new ObjectFactory();
JAXBElement<GetBillInfo> jbx = of.createGetBillInfo(gbi);
```

There's no need to actually use Spring here, but of course you can define beans for the service, etc., no problem there.

Comment: It created following classes 
1)Bill.java
2)BillInfo.java
3)GetBillInfo.java
4)GetBillInfoResponse.java
5)ObjectFactory.java
6)ViewBillInfo.java (Interface)
7)ViewBillInfo_Service.java

Comment: Then try using ViewBillInfo_Service to actually communicate with the web service.

Comment: ViewBillInfo_Service vis=new ViewBillInfo_Service();
  ViewBillInfo port= vis.getViewBillInfoPort();
it is giving runtime exception

Comment: of invalid invocation

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.annotation.AnnotationReader

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36557308/caused-by-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-sun-xml-bind-v2-model-annotatio

Comment: ViewBillInfo port= vis.getViewBillInfoPort();
  ObjectFactory of1=new ObjectFactory();
  JAXBElement<GetBillInfo> jbx1 = of1.createGetBillInfo(gbi);

Comment: however jbx1 have null in it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145611/discussion-between-jahangeer-and-florian-schaetz).

Answer (score 0):

Open your command prompt and you have to enter wsimport command `wsimport -p xxx.xxx.xxx -s D:\xxx\xxx http://xxxx:8080/xxxx/xxx?wsdl`

here -s is a source folder which you have to create in your system.Once you execute this command you will get java file, copy that java file to your project.
Then 
`  YourSoapBindingService obj = new YourSoapBindingService ();
   YourService service = obj.getSoapBindingPort();
   service.callYourServiceMethod();

`

Answer (score 0):

in addition to other answers
wsimport is present in JDK installed directory for example for me its 
**C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin**
there is a file wsimport
right click in the directory and use wsimport -Xnocompile pathToYOURWSDL and it will generate you java code,