# Java 'AnnotationReader' class not found

Tags: java

I am getting following error while running build.

```
Log:-
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/xml/bind/v2/model/annotation/AnnotationReader
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
```

Can you please help me resolving this issue. I found some reference which didnt help me.
I kept the jar files which has above class in Classpath. Still facing the same issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.annotation.AnnotationReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36557308/caused-by-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-sun-xml-bind-v2-model-annotatio)

Comment: Its saying 'you need to simply use below maven dependencies:' Mine is not a maven project. When i try to run java command i am hitting above issue.

Comment: Then you must add these dependencies manually on the classpath.