# JAXBContext not working in Java 17.0.3 (It was working in java 11)

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, javax.imageio, xml-to-json

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Instances.class);
            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

            Instances instances = (Instances) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new File("test.xml"));

            return new ResponseEntity<>(new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(instances), HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
```

I have this code working in java 11 (converting xml file to json) but when I switch to java 17 this part of code stopped working.

I also have added two dependencies of javax

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.activation/activation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>`
```

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvgOs.png)

If any extra details require feel free to ask.

```
2023-07-14T23:46:57.734+05:30  INFO 96452 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-07-14T23:46:57.736+05:30  INFO 96452 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
2023-07-14T23:46:57.800+05:30  INFO 96452 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.l.s.s.Service.BackendProcessService    : status reading started
2023-07-14T23:46:57.823+05:30 ERROR 96452 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/xml/bind/v2/model/annotation/AnnotationReader] with root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.annotation.AnnotationReader
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1012) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:862) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:760) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:681) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:639) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3402) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getMethodsRecursive(Class.java:3543) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3529) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2225) ~[na:na]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:295) ~[jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar:2.3.0]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:286) ~[jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar:2.3.0]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:409) ~[jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar:2.3.0]
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:721) ~[jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar:2.3.0]
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:662) ~[jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar:2.3.0]
    at com.lowes.self_service_tool.self_service_backend.Service.BackendProcessService.status(BackendProcessService.java:78) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.lowes.self_service_tool.self_service_backend.Controller.BackendProcessController.status(BackendProcessController.java:27) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:152) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:6.0]
```

I thought in java 17 this will get updated but not getting upgrading version is giving errors in same code.

Comment: Have you recompiled ALL your code with Java 17? Are all your dependencies compatible with Java 17?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You might want to upgrade to [Jakarta XML bind](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.xml.bind/jakarta.xml.bind-api) and [Jakarta activation](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.activation/jakarta.activation-api). When doing that, make sure to change the package names from `javax` to `jakarta`.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of [Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.annotation.AnnotationReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36557308/caused-by-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-sun-xml-bind-v2-model-annotatio). Review the answers and associated comments for advice on changes you need to make to your pom.xml. Note that some information there is no longer valid because of the age of that question, but the underlying issue is the same as yours. More recent answers there are more likely to be helpful - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/55297661/2985643

Comment: Also, please be sure to update your question if you try other solutions that did not work for you.