# Jersey 2.25.1 HTTP STATUS 500 Error when using MediaType.APPLICATION_XML

Tags: web-services, rest, annotations, jersey

Since 2 days I am stuck with this issue and it is not going away.

A simple explanation what I want to do:

1) build a simple Restful web service using jersey 2.25.1 which displays XML as the output.

2) Deploy it on Tomcat

**Just for Info** My JSON and plain text restful webservice is working fine. I am only getting errors for XML when using @RootElement. I am using java 1.8, Jersy 2.25.1, tomcat 8.5

I am getting the below error again and again and don't understand how to resolve it:

[image: Error Image]

I have tried these two examples as well but no luck:

1) https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/download-xml-with-jersey-jaxb/

I have tried multiple examples but still, This error shows up and I cannot resolve it. Can some one please explain me why this is coming up.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Check https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-comsunxmlbindv2modelannotationannotationreader/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27046836/why-has-annotationreader-been-removed-from-jaxb-reference-implementation link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you everyone I fixed the issue... maybe this info will help everyone who is searching for the problem. The major problem was that I don't know for what reason If I make a new maven project on eclipse with **Group Id** org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes **Artifact Id** jersey-quickstart-webapp **version** 2.25.1, eclipse used to create a whole project with POM file as it suppose to and in this project if I even ran https://jersey.java.net/documentation/2.5.1/media.html#d0e7129
 this simple jersey official demo, I was getting the same annotation error. I think in the POM file which eclipse create has a lot of things which I didn't needed and which must be overlapping with other things.

So in the above mkyong example I just added below dependency and it is now working just fine:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.11</version>
</dependency>
```

Thanks everyone for helping me out. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just a little update, even updating
I am also creating basic `Jeresy` webApp and faced same issue, but this above solution is not enough.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.11</version>
</dependency>
```

After building and on hit our endpoint, one new issue will come

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/xml/bind/v2/model/annotation/AnnotationReader
```

To resolve this you need to add following dependencies too into `pom.xml`

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0.1</version>
</dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-impl -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

So this is the complete solution, to make your `Jeresy` webApp work