# difference between com.sun.xml.bind jaxb-impl.jar and javax.xml jaxb-impl.jar

Tags: java, jaxb, sun

What is the difference between jaxb-impl.jar with maven groupId javax.xml and a jaxb-impl.jar with maven groupId com.sun.xml.bind?

Comment: Since "linux" is part of your name, I would suggest you try `unzip -p jaxb-impl.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF | grep Version` where *jaxb-impl.jar* should be replaced with one of the jar files, then run the same command on the other jar file.  I expect this will show that the jar files represent different JAXB versions.  (META-INF/MANIFEST.MF is the jar file's manifest, which contains meta-data about the archive.)

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26413431/which-artifacts-should-i-use-for-jaxb-ri-in-my-maven-project