# What is the difference between jaxb-core and jaxb-impl

Tags: jaxb

Under what scenario i need to choose between `jaxb-impl` vs `jaxb-core`?
having both `jaxb-impl` and `jaxb-core` in my project would cause any class loading conflicts?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26413431/which-artifacts-should-i-use-for-jaxb-ri-in-my-maven-project/26413432#26413432

Comment: I don't see the difference between the two explained.

Comment: Trying to create a uber jar with Maven's shaded plugin returns: jakarta.activation-1.2.1.jar, jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar define 31 overlapping classes:

Answer (score 0):

If you go by the `com.sun.xml.bind` artifacts in Maven Central it seems [`jaxb-core`](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-core/4.0.1/jaxb-core-4.0.1.pom) is a underlying (shared) dependency of [`jaxb-impl`](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/4.0.1/jaxb-impl-4.0.1.pom), `jaxb-xjc` and `jaxb-jxc`); thus you would **require** `jaxb-core` to work with `jaxb-impl`.

```xml
<!-- jaxb-impl -->
<!-- ... --->
    <!-- ... --->
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>Old JAXB Runtime</name>
    <description>Old JAXB Runtime module. Contains sources required for runtime processing.</description>
    <url>https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jaxb-ri/</url>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    <!-- ... -->
<!-- ... --->
```

```xml
<!-- jaxb-core -->
<!-- ... --->
    <!-- ... -->
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>Old JAXB Core</name>
    <description>Old JAXB Core module. Contains sources required by XJC, JXC and Runtime modules with dependencies.</description>
    <url>https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jaxb-ri/</url>
    <!-- ... -->
<!-- ... -->
```