# Spring Boot 2 project works in IDE but not command line

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I am running a Spring Boot project.  I can run the project from IntelliJ, however when I try and do `mvn spring-boot:run` I get `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException`

I have included

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

in my pom.xml file.  I have even included `java.xml.bind` as an add modules in the pom.  But the issue still persists.  What am I missing?

Comment: Class not found is `javax/xml/bind/JAXBException` and is not from `com.sun.xml.bind` which you are trying to add. Which version of java are you running from command line?

Comment: I am running Java 9

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26413431/which-artifacts-should-i-use-for-jaxb-ri-in-my-maven-project

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-in-j. The dependency suggested there is: `<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to @jny for the answer

I had the wrong dependency in the pom file.  Replacing it with

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId> 
   <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId> 
   <version>2.3.0</version> 
</dependency>
```

corrected the issue.