# jaxb2-maven-plugin an m2e connector

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, m2e, jaxb2-maven-plugin

After clean checkout/clone from repo, I get this error in eclipse on the execution of the jaxb2-maven-plugin xjc goal.
After "Update Maven Configuration" the code is still not generated.
In my neon3 eclipse(4.6.3) I have installed the m2e plugin(1.7.1) together with the "m2e connector for jaxb2"(4.0.0)

```
null (org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:2.2:xjc:xjc-evu:generate-sources)

org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException
    at org.codehaus.mojo.jaxb2.javageneration.AbstractJavaGeneratorMojo.performExecution(AbstractJavaGeneratorMojo.java:482)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.jaxb2.AbstractJaxbMojo.execute(AbstractJaxbMojo.java:257)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl$11.call(MavenImpl.java:1362)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl$11.call(MavenImpl.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1360)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.MojoExecutionBuildParticipant.build(MojoExecutionBuildParticipant.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilderImpl.build(MavenBuilderImpl.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.execute(MavenBuilder.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder.build(MavenBuilder.java:200)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:735)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:301)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:304)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:383)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.codehaus.mojo.jaxb2.shared.environment.ToolExecutionEnvironment.restore(ToolExecutionEnvironment.java:182)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.jaxb2.javageneration.AbstractJavaGeneratorMojo.performExecution(AbstractJavaGeneratorMojo.java:427)
    ... 33 more
```

In the same pom.xml it is marked under lifecycle-mapping as

```
<action>
    <execute>
        <runOnIncremental>false</runOnIncremental>
        <runOnConfiguration>true</runOnConfiguration>
    </execute>
</action>
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6653702/2063989) stands that the bitstrings connector should support the jaxb2-maven-plugin and in [this comment from the Author](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=352056#c14) I can see there is support since version 1.0.3.201107311209. Nevertheless on the authors homepage it is stated

> Plugin: org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin Home:
>
> http://mojo.codehaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin
>
> (Note: not required for jaxb2-maven-plugin version 1.5+)

Which m2e connector or pom.xml configuration should I use to make jaxb2-maven-plugin work in eclipse (Meaning, it will generate surces in the generate-sources phase on update configuration and add the generated folder into classpath) ?

Answer (score 0):

**My workaround:** After clean checkout, run the Maven `generate-sources` phase manually, and configure build-helper plugin to add the jaxb folder as resources folder into eclipse project (for this you need of course the m2e connector for `build-helper-maven-plugi`n )

Answer (score 0):

`mvn clean install` worked for me.