# Is there a way to deal with duplicate element definitions across multiple .xsd files in JAXB?

Tags: java, maven, jaxb, maven-plugin, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I have dozens and dozens `.xsd` files that I want to auto-generate code for. A couple of the files have duplicate names that clash when I try to generate all of them at the same time.

I am focusing on just trying to get 2 of these to work.

When I get these 2 working I will fix the rest. But I am just focusing on 2 of these files for now. I am not in control of them, they are from a vendor and follow a *"standard"*, so **editing them is not an option** for multiple reasons.

I am using the `maven-jaxb2-plugin` to process these files.

I added a `binding.xjb` file as suggested in the link in `mat b`'s answer and other instructions I have found on the web. But I am getting the following errors, an no output.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jxb:bindings version="2.1"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance"
              xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
              xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
              xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
              xsi:schemaLocation=" http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/bindingschema_2_0.xsd">
  <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="mac-3.4.xsd">
    <jxb:schemaBindings>
      <jxb:package name="my.company.mac"/>
    </jxb:schemaBindings>
  </jxb:bindings>
  <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="mac-stylesheet-3.4.xsd">
    <jxb:schemaBindings>
      <jxb:package name="my.company.stylesheet"/>
    </jxb:schemaBindings>
  </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

gives the following error

```
[ERROR] Error while parsing schema(s).Location [ file:/C:/Users/Jarrod%20Roberson/Projects/spa-tools/spa-lib/src/main/sc
hema/mac-stylesheet-3.4.xsd{165,33}].
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: 'halign' is already defined
```

The offending element is : ( there are many others this is just the first one that clashes )

```
<xsd:simpleType name="halign">
  <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
    <xsd:enumeration value="left" />
    <xsd:enumeration value="center" />
    <xsd:enumeration value="right" />
  </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

And is identical in each of the `.xsd` files, how do I resolve this duplication with either only one class being generated or each one being generated in to their own package namespace?

This isn't the only duplicate element like this there are lots of them, so just trying to remove them from the files isn't a option either.

This `halign` is in multiple `.xsd` files and I want to either put them in their individual packages, or be able to tell the compiler to use the first one that was generated.

This is where I started off before I tried an external `.xjb` file, by just specifying the `package` in the `pom.xml`.

**How do I configure the binding to either ignore the duplicate configurations, map them to separate packages or map them to existing implementations?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have a half-way workaround solution to this, but it is very time intensive.
I had to create a separate `<execution/>` for every one of the files that has duplicate entries.

```
<executions>
  <execution>
    <id>jaxb-mac</id>
    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
    <goals>
      <goal>generate</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
      <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>
      <generatePackage>my.company.mac</generatePackage>
      <schemaDirectory>src/main/schema</schemaDirectory>
      <schemaIncludes>
        <include>mac-3.4.xsd</include>
      </schemaIncludes>
    </configuration>
  </execution>
  <execution>
    <id>jaxb-stylesheet</id>
    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
    <goals>
      <goal>generate</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
      <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>
      <generatePackage>my.company.stylesheet</generatePackage>
      <schemaDirectory>src/main/schema</schemaDirectory>
      <schemaIncludes>
        <include>mac-stylesheet-3.4.xsd</include>
      </schemaIncludes>
    </configuration>
  </execution>
```

The `<forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>` is important or only the first `<execution/>` will run and the rest will think that there is no need to run because I am generating into the same directory.

I would still like a less labor intensive solution to deal with the duplicates.

I think if I make the first master .xsd a separate module that builds into its own .jar file, I could then use the `<episode/>` tag and have it skip generating the same duplicate elements over and over, since they are identical in definition.

*I have since decided to abandon XML if at all possible and JAXB completely. There are newer and better ways to parse XML and map it to objects as of this edit.*

Comment: `<forceRegenerate>` is no longer available in `maven-jaxb2-plugin:2.2`.

Answer (score 5):

Realize this is old, but I had the same error and could it resolve it by **not specifying a target package**, i.e. the -b option with xjc.  Then the duplicate elements each get created in their own namespace package and no conflict.

Comment: Commenting to highlight this as the *actual* answer, at least for me - removing the `<generatePackage>` element in my `maven-jaxb2-plugin` config in pom fixed this same problem for me.

Comment: the easiest solution! worked for me after hoooours  of searching!

Comment: Can you please post your maven-jaxb2-plugin config. It seems that your solution is not working for me.

Answer (score 3):

I post my solution for **gradle**, it solves duplicate issue and does`not require xjb files:

```
task generateJaxb() {
    ext.sourcesDir = "${buildDir}/generated-sources/jaxb"
    ext.classesDir = "${buildDir}/classes/jaxb"
    ext.schemaDir = "src/resources/schemas"
    ext.tmp = "${buildDir}/tmp/xjc"

    doLast() {
        project.ant {
            taskdef name: "xjc", classname: "com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask",
                    classpath: configurations.jaxb.asPath

            delete(dir: tmp)
            mkdir(dir: tmp)
            delete(dir: sourcesDir)
            delete(dir: classesDir)
            mkdir(dir: sourcesDir)
            mkdir(dir: classesDir)
        }

        fileTree(schemaDir){
            include '**/*.xsd'
            include '**/*.wsdl'
        }.each{File file->
            //println file
            project.ant {
                taskdef name: "xjc", classname: "com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask",
                        classpath: configurations.jaxb.asPath
                xjc(destdir: tmp, schema:"${file.getAbsolutePath()}") {
                    arg(value: "-wsdl")
                    produces(dir: tmp, includes: "**/*.java")
                }
                copy(todir: sourcesDir) {
                    fileset(dir: tmp, erroronmissingdir: false) {
                        include(name: "**/*.java")
                    }
                }
                delete(dir: tmp)
                mkdir(dir: tmp)
            }
        }
        project.ant {
            javac(destdir: classesDir, source: 1.6, target: 1.6, debug: true,
                    debugLevel: "lines,vars,source",
                    classpath: configurations.jaxb.asPath) {
                src(path: sourcesDir)
                include(name: "**/*.java")
                include(name: "*.java")
            }

            copy(todir: classesDir) {
                fileset(dir: sourcesDir, erroronmissingdir: false) {
                    exclude(name: "**/*.java")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

configurations {
    jaxb
}

dependencies {
    jaxb("com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:2.2.4-1")
    compile(files(generateJaxb.classesDir).builtBy(generateJaxb))
}

jar {
    from generateJaxb.classesDir
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a `<schemaBindings>` element to the XSD:

```
<schemaBindings>
    <package name="com.whatever.stuff" />
</schemaBindings>
```

[Source](http://blog.frankel.ch/customize-your-jaxb-bindings)

Comment: I don't want to modify the source `.xsd` and I can't get multiple external `.xjb` files to work either, any ideas. I can't find a clear explanation of how to process multiple files into multiple packages.

Comment: "I don't want to modify the source .xsd" - why not? Seems simple enough. It's just metadata.

Comment: Do you have `xsi:schemaLocation="
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/bindingschema_2_0.xsd"` in the root element of your .xjb file?

Comment: I finally got the name space issues figured out and this doesn't actually solve the root cause of my problem, which is trying to deal with duplicate element definitions. I have edited my question to better reflect the actual root cause that brought me here.

Comment: this fails if there are duplicate elements in any of the `.xsd` files, which ended up being my root cause

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar problem: we had one wsdl file and two xsd files in the same directory. The wsdl file imports the two xsd files. The problem was that JAXB was taking all three files into consideration and throwing '... is already defined' error. It was basically complaining that it saw the same element in both wsdl and xsd file.

We could fix this issue in the **maven plugin configuration (in pom.xml)** by adding an **exclude** tag as in the following example:

```
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.12.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                <generatePackage>mywsdl.wsdl</generatePackage>
                <args><arg>-XautoNameResolution</arg></args>
                <schemas>
                    <schema>
                        <fileset>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>*.xsd</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </fileset>
                    </schema>
                </schemas>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```