# maven: which jaxb plugin to use?

Tags: maven, jaxb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference of Maven JAXB plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432859/difference-of-maven-jaxb-plugins)

I see there are several plugins available:

- com.sun.tools.xjc.maven2:maven-jaxb-plugin
- org.codehaus.mojo:xjc-maven-plugin
- org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin
- org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin

Which one should I use (to generate jaxb classes from xsd)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a question that you could find helpful: [Difference of Maven JAXB plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2432859/838434).

Truly, the `com.sun.tools.xjc.maven2:maven-jaxb-plugin` seems to be dead, it also offers few configuration options. I used it for a while, then switched to `org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin` when I found a need to customize the generation to the extent the Sun's plugin could not cope with.

I haven't used the `org.codehaus.mojo:xjc-maven-plugin`, but it seems to be a subset of the more versatile `org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin`. As for the last one, the `org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin`, no personal experience, either, but the dead links on the terse documentation page are not encouraging.