# Maven Jaxb2 xjc plugin error No schemas have been found

Tags: maven, xsd, jaxb2

These days I've spent some time on JAXB for converting XSD to Java Class and vice versa. Here's a very good tutorial for beginners, http://www.journaldev.com/1312/how-to-generate-java-classes-from-xsd-using-xjc-maven-plugin. I follow the steps strictly, but always get error when `mvn clean install`

Here's my `pom.xml` file.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>jd</groupId>
    <artifactId>jd</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Plugin required to build java classes from XSD using XJC -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>xjc</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>xjc</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                   <!-- The name of your generated source package -->
                    <arguments>-extension -npa -b ${project.basedir}/src/main/java/com/moodys/jaxb/global.xjb</arguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

But when I type `mvn clean install`, it always give me error as following:

```
C:\Users\congy\Desktop\Work\workspace\JaxbFromClass>mvn clean jaxb2:xjc
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building jd 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ jd ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\congy\Desktop\Work\workspace\JaxbFromClass\target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- jaxb2-maven-plugin:1.5:xjc (default-cli) @ jd ---
[INFO] Generating source...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.487s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Jul 04 19:09:37 CST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 4M/122M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:1.5:xjc (default-cli) on project jd: No schemas have been found -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Can anyone show me the cause or simply tell me what should I refer to for further information?

Another question is : according to this question [Difference of Maven JAXB plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432859/difference-of-maven-jaxb-plugins), there's at least three jaxb plugins. So all of these plugins are all generated for the same purposes? If so ,why?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As you did not provide any `schemaDirectory`, the plugin is trying to generate Java sources from all XML schema files in [the default schema directory](http://www.mojohaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/xjc-mojo.html#schemaDirectory). You should configure the plugin according to the [documentation](http://www.mojohaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/usage.html) :

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.5</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>id1</id>
      <goals>
    <goal>xjc</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
       <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/jaxb</outputDirectory>
       <packageName>com.your.package.jaxb</packageName>
       <schemaDirectory>src/main/xsd</schemaDirectory>
       <schemaFiles>jaxb.xsd</schemaFiles>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Try to remove following line:
    <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/jaxb</outputDirectory>

Answer (score 6):

Try to make sure that **jaxb.xsd** is present under **src/main/resources**, the plugin is waring since it coudn't find the scheme in the specified location.

Comment: What is actually jaxb.xsd? Is it a file name?

Comment: @zygimantus yes, it's the schema of which you want to generate Java object classes

Answer (score 1):

We can use as below in pom.xml file

```
   <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>id1</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>xjc</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>src/main/java</outputDirectory>
                    <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
                    <packageName>com.subu.xsd.model</packageName>
                    <schemaDirectory>src/main/java/schemadir</schemaDirectory>
                    <schemaFiles>XYZ.xsd</schemaFiles>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

The OP already got their answer, but I ran into this same problem for a different reason...

I introduced a new class that JAXB wasn't generating source for. This is because I used a parameterized constructor. Once I added a no-arg constructor the problem was fixed.