# Spring SOAP - Producing Web Services

Tags: web-services, spring-boot, soap

I'm new in SOAP.

I must communicate with external company by using SOAP Web Services like following use case :

external company send to me soap request (ex : ask for destinataire list) and I send back data.

So, to do that they provide me wsdl file

After reading a lot of tuto, soap is little confuse for me. 
Can you confirm that "Consuming Web service" part is for external comapny ex : https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/

And "producing web service" part is for me ?
https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/

External company ask me to indicate url with wisdl file ... I don't understand what they mean

- Where do I copy wisdl file in my code (Which folder ? I use Eclipse) ?
- Must I code all methods defined in wsdl file (I don't use all of them) ?
- Do I need xsd files as I can see in tuto or is it for "consuming ws " part ?

Answer (score 0):

OK,

Q1: in folder defined in config file

Q2: No

Q3: No

sources : [How to use WSDL with spring-boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33773346/how-to-use-wsdl-with-spring-boot)