# error: eclipse m2e "Could not process schema"

Tags: java, eclipse, m2e

I am a new programmer to a maven web project, and m2e in eclipse gives an error that others tell me to ignore but I would like to fix. A clean and rebuild in eclipse marks the `<execution>` tag as an error, and hovering over it shows the following:

```
Could not process schema:
  projectXsdOne.xsd (org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:1.2:xjc:JAXBStringifiedGeneration:generate-sources)

org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Could not process schema:
  projectXsdOne.xsd
  at org.codehaus.mojo.jaxb2.XjcMojo.execute(XjcMojo.java:313)
  at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
  at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:331)
  at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl$11.call(MavenImpl.java:1362)
```

There was one post about a very similar error that the poster originally fixed by adding `<xmlSchema>` and `<wsdl>` tags of false and true, respectively, to the `<configuration>` portion of the `<execution>` tag, but that didn't eliminate my error. The web application does seem to run, but I hate having an error "on the boards" and just ignoring it. Does anyone know what else I might try to fix it?

I'm running eclipse photon, m2e 1.9.0 (configured to run "embedded"), java JDK 1.8.0_51, Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

There exists multiple JAXB plugins for Maven.
Have a look at: [difference-of-maven-jaxb-plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432859/difference-of-maven-jaxb-plugins)

The different plugins varies in age and activity, and the support for them by the m2e plugin have historically not been that great.

You can try some of the other plugins, or maybe try to exchange it for another plugin like e.g. [The CXF XJC Maven Plugin](http://cxf.apache.org/cxf-xjc-plugin.html), and see if it makes a difference.
Otherwise you will probably have to accept the fact that Maven support in Eclipse is not complete, and ignore the error or [ignore the plugin goal](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/documentation/m2e-execution-not-covered.html#ignore-plugin-goal).

Comment: thanks -- I have one from org.bitstrings (org.bitstrings.eclipse.m2e.connectiors.jaxb2.feature.feature.group), which is not on the comparison question you gave me. I'm not allowed to change plugins without involving IT to install software, so will look for other things.